# SQL - Moving positions from one portfolio to another

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL query that will move positions from one group (Groupabcd) to a different existing Group (GroupEFGH). All positions are held in a table named 'holdings'

The end result should have no positions left in GroupABCD.

Ex)

Current Table:

```
GroupABCD
Holdings:
Google
Apple
IBM

GroupEFHG
Holdings: 
Facebook
Twitter
```

End Result:

```
GroupABCP:
No Holdings

GroupEFHG:
Holdings:
Facebook
Twitter
Apple
Google
IBM
```

Comment: Post your schema.

Comment: It's totally unclear on how your tables are defined. Please **[edit]** your question and add the create table statements for those tables. Also: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: PLease post your schema set up and any ways you have tried to accomplish this on your on.  It should be a rather simple update command.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
DECLARE @toDelete TABLE (del_Holdings  NVARCHAR(100))
MERGE GroupEFHG t
USING GroupABCD s
ON t.Holdings= s.Holdings
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (Holdings)
  VALUES (s.Holdings)
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.Holdings into @toDelete;

DELETE ABCD FROM GroupABCD ABCD INNER JOIN @toDelete on Holdings = del_Holdings
```